# How to get text from span->li->ul-> Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have cart full with Elements 
This Ex of one of them

```
    <div class="item-container cart-item">
    <div>
    <img border="0" onerror="src='http://www.myengravedjewelry.com/Admin/surfing.jpg'" title="Bloody Mary Style Colour Name Necklace" src="http://www.myengravedjewelry.com/Admin/surfing.jpg" alt="1009">
    <div class="item-header">
    <div class="item-body">
    <ul class="item-ul">
    <li>
    <li>
   <li>
    <span class="bold-14">Price:14.9 </span>
    </li>
      <li>
  <span>ShortId:1010 </span>
   </li>
   <li>
   <span>LongId:110-01-073-10 </span>
   </li>
      <li>
    <span class="spanDefCat">DefaultCat:334 </span>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-footer"></div>
    </div>
```

When i press save i go trow each one of this element and check if  DefaultCat==0

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-item");
```

and i try to get to this defaulCat like this

```
for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++){


        var elementContent=elements[i].find(".spanDefCat").html();
        var vars = elementContent.split(" ");
        var obj = {};
        vars.forEach(function(v) {
        var keyValue = v.split(":");
        obj[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];


    });
           DefaultCat = obj["DefaultCat"];
           ShortId = elements[i].children[1].alt;//New  style to take ShortID
            if(DefaultCat==0)setDefaultCatToProductId(parseInt(ShortId));
            arrSortedOrder[i]=parseInt(ShortId);

    }
```

Any one know how to get to this value?
p.s
Plz Do NOT give me solution with $(.spanDefCat) because when i find deff=0 i need to take ShordId as Well from this element[i]

Comment: You've tagged the question as jQuery, but there's nothing related to it here.

Comment: in jQuery you can get "DefaultCat:334" like this: `$('.cart-item span').innerHtml();`

Comment: So... what you're trying to do is to find the value of `DefaultCat`? If so, @GintasK just answered.

Comment: I edit my question i have more span in me ul and i need to get DefaultCat and know from with elements in comes

Comment: this is the worst approach I ever seen, you should delete it all and start all over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".cart-item").each(function(){
    var shortId = $(this).find(".bold-14").parent("li").siblings("li").children("span").html();
    var shortItem = shortId.replace(' ','').split(":");
    var defaultCat = $(this).find(".spanDefCat").html();
    var item = defaultCat.replace(' ','').split(":");  
    if(item[1]==0){
        var id = parseInt(shortItem[1]);
        //do something
    }else{
        var id = parseInt(shortItem[1]);
        //do something else
    }
    console.log(defaultCat);
    console.log(shortId);
});
```

***Note:*** Above code give you the **DefaultCat:334** and **ShortId:1010** so now you can use both in if else statement.
If the format of **DefaultCat:334** is same for all cart item then you can check whether it is **0 or not**

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VM366/)

Comment: I need to check all elements with for(i=0....){ if(defaul==0) then i take his ID and change his deffcat By id  sow i cant jast do find spanDefCat it have to be found in for() with element[i] that i can take the id if this element

Comment: @VovaPotapov If its useful to you then accept this answer so that tihs will help to other users too if they find this answer with right sign. thanks

Comment: @Dh.. Why i need to accept the wrong answer i explaned that i need to find this deffCat in the for( element[i]) and not just to do $select and find the all .spanDefCat .html()...

Comment: @VovaPotapov i have updated my answer with your requirement. now you are having the id which contains the value of shortId so you can use inside the if else statement. i have also added jsfiddle link with working code so you can execute the code there for your reference. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see JQuery tag so i give you a response with JQuery statements.

```
$(".cart-item").find(".spanDefCat").each(function(index, domEle){
    //get text, delete spaces and split
    split_result = $(domEle).text().replace(' ','').split(":");
    //get only numeric value as string
    defaultCat = split_result[1];
    //parse into int
    defaultCat = parseInt(defaultCat);
    //if your var is equal to 0
    if(defaultCat == 0){
        /********************* 
        * Type you code here *
        **********************/
    }
});
```